# How to get records in order from database materialized view using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, sql-order-by

First I create database view where I have the records ordered.
But when I try to do "Skip" and "Take" they are not ordered.

```
var query = dbContext.UserView.OrderBy(x => x.Id);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var users = await query
    .Skip(i)
    .Take(1)
    .ToListAsync();
    
    await SendMessage(users);
}
```

I am trying to take and send records on chunks but I don't want to load them in memory.

If I don't order `var query = dbContext.UserView.OrderBy(x => x.Id);` here, I receive different order each time in my for loop even though I create my database view with "order by".

When I call ToListAsync(), will it order every time and become a slower query.

Is there a way to create the database view and every time when I ask for records to keep the same order?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Database Views are **NEVER** ordered by definition. The CREATE or ALTER statement for the view will fail if there is an ORDER BY clause. In this case, though, you cover for it with the `.OrderBy()` call from the dbContext.

Additionally, it's usually best to avoid calling `ToList()` or `ToListAysnc()` before you need to, and in this case you probably don't need to.

As for the ordering... this is what `async` code is for: it lets you do work on one thing while still `await`-ing another. The result is things don't always run in the order you expected. But there are some things we can do to help.

Finally, the way the loop is structured this would have sent **10 separate queries to the database**. *That's bad.* In fact, it's probably the main source of the strange ordering, as the other async operations should all finish nearly instantly and so avoid most of the reordering issues.

You want it to look more like this instead:

```
var query = dbContext.UserView.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(10);
foreach(var user in query)
{
     await SendMessage(user);
}
```

Of if `SendMessge()` can only accept a sequence:

```
var query = dbContext.UserView.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(10);
await SendMessage(query);
```

And if (and only if!) `SendMessage()` absolutely demands a list (and given the requirement from the comments to still only have one item in memory), we can still improve performance by only running ONE query:

```
var query = await dbContext.UserView.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Take(10);
foreach(var user in query)
{
    //guessing at the type name here)
    var list = new List<User>() {user} ;
    await SendMessage(list);
}
```

Again: the above only runs ONE query on the database, but still only has ONE item in memory at a time.

---

But in this last situation I'd probably first explore whether I could also change or overload `SendMessage()` to allow an `IEnumerable<User>`. That is, the method probably looks like something like this:

```
public static async void SendMessage(List<User> users)
{
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        //send the message
    }
}
```

And if so you can change it like this:

```
public static async void SendMessage(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        //send the message
    }
}
```

Note the code in method did not change... only the function signature. Best of all, you can **still pass a list to the method when you call it.** And now you can also pass any other enumerable, including the version from the second code sample in this answer.

Comment: I actually want to make new database query every time because the records are too much and don't want to load them in memory, but don't want to do orderBy every time, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @nnchvxx  "`The records are too much and don't want to load them into memory`." **That's exactly why you don't call ToList()!** Avoiding `ToList()` lets you loop through ALL the records, but only have ONE in memory at a time! But more than that, if there's a lot of data in each record, then **don't load all the columns!** Give yourself a way to only select the columns you need.